# Change document font keeping accents

Tags: fonts

I've changed the whole document font with

```
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

but my code for special characters as accents

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
```

isn't working now which gives me problems because I wrote accents as "árbol" instead of "'arbol", and I'd like to keep writing this way.

The whole preamble is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro} %https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/


\begin{document}
árbol y no \'arbol
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't see why it doesn't work. Could you post a small complete code reproducing the problem?

Comment: Hi @Bernard, done!

Comment: I can’t duplicate your bug. On TeX Live 2020, it works fine.

Comment: Well, I have no problem to compile (except for the graphic file in the header). Did you install the font package recently?

Comment: @Davislor you mean "árbol" is well compiled? I use texworks on a mac

Comment: @Bernard honestly I just took the code from https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/raleway/. I didn't know I had to install the package font :O . The problem isn't compile, it is to keep the accent when it compiles :(

Comment: I don't understand. What sourcesans pro has to do with raleway?

Comment: @Bernard excuse me, It was my misstake. https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/ was the right link.

Comment: What is your distribution? TeX Live or MiKTeX?

Comment: @Bernard runing```pdflatex --version``` in the terminal it show TeX Live 2016

Comment: It should be time to update! Many  things have change since 2016. Before that, just in case, run from the console `initexmf --mkmaps` to refresh the type 1 fonts database.

Comment: @Bernard I didn't know they had to be updated haha. I'm currently struggling with it getting many error messages (typing what you told me, and doing what other posts tells what I have to do, which is very stressful). Thank you, I'm going to try!

Comment: @UnPerrito  unfortunately, I can't help much, except for general advice, because I'm under MiKTeX.

Comment: I think it's obvious, but you are using TeX = UTF-8 encoding, right?

Comment: @SimonDispa I don't know why but because of your comment I googled "utf-8" to know what it is, and, adding ```\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}``` it worked hahaha. Thanks!!

Comment: @UnPerrito Ah! Yes, that’s been the default since 2018. You should upgrade. (Unless you absolutely must write documents for someone who still uses the old version.)

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer. Only to report that I got  what it seems to be the correct output, both with `pdflatex` and `lualatex`. (win7 + TeXstudio + MikTeX, none of which I think is relevant)

Using `sourcesanspro.sty    2018/05/19 v2.7 Adobe's Source Sans Pro typeface`

Installed from https://ctan.org/pkg/sourcesanspro?lang=en

The `.otf` installed files were created  on 26-Apr-20.

`% TeX encoding = UTF-8` **<<<< important!**

[image: z]

```
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8 %% use this directive or add \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro} %https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/sourcesanspro/    

\begin{document}

    árbol y no \'arbol
    
    cigüeña     
    
    ágape
    
    bebé
    
    abogacía
    
    ocasión
    
    última
        
\end{document}
```